# How can I save HTTP GET Response to a var using Express (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, http, express, get

I am using Express in Nodejs in order to make a GET Call. As a response, I get the value that I need, but when I return the value from my function to the main I get undefined.

```
function getInfo() 
{

      var oauth = getoAuth();

      request.get({
        url:'myurl',   
        oauth:oauth, 
        qs:null, 
        json:true
      }, 
          function (e, r, data) {
            body.data = data;
            body.emit('update');
      }); 


      body.on('update', function () {
        console.log(body.data.issues[0].key);
        return (body.data.issues[0].key);  
      });

}
```

This key is what I need. When I print it in the console I get the correct value, but it doesn't return anything, because it is an async call. How can I return the value? Can I somehow wait for the value using express? I saw on stackoverflow that some people used this body.on('update'... solution, but it didn't work for me. It still saves nothing to a variable.

## EDIT-> the response:

```
TESTING: undefined
THEKEY1
```

## Saving the value at:

> var myid= geInfo();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :

```
function getInfo() 
{

      var oauth = getoAuth();

      request.get({ url:'myurl',  oauth:oauth,  qs:null, json:true},
        function (error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response && response.statusCode==200){
               console.log(body);
               return body.data.issues[0].key;  
            }else{
               return null;
            }
      }); 
}
```

Comment: Dear @Saurabh, again the same :( I also tried to put  const theid = body.issues[0].key; return theid; but again I get undefined as return in the main. And the console puts the correct one out. :(

Comment: you got undefined , because of that property not exists in body object

Comment: @TeslaX , make sure you write correct key  `body.data.issues[0].key; `

Comment: @TeslaX , can you please paste response in your question

Comment: I did, because when I print it out it is the correct one.  body.data.issues[0].key; ( I am sorry I wrote it in the comment wrong, but in the code it is correct)

Comment: it doesn't work. I still get undefined. As on the beginning. It comes out "TESTING: undefined". Couse, it is still async.